# Why does my SO question have so few views?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, views

I raised a question on stack overflow yesterday and at the time of writing this, it's only had six views.

Can anyone tell me why? Or give me some tips to improve my question?

Here it is:

[How can I get an Oracle connection pool shared across all applications/virtual directories/versions in my IIS instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23050956/connection-pooling-with-iis-net-to-an-oracle-database)

I *thought* it was kinda straight forward, and related to some large technological areas so I was expecting a fair few people to have an opinion on it, or at least to "view" it.

Did I word it poorly?

Are my tags wrong?

Is there something wrong with my account?

EDIT:
As a comparison, this post (that you're currently reading) already has THIRTEEN views and I only posted it twenty one minutes ago. Which seems counter intuitive to me as I'd expect StackOverflow to have many more active user than Meta StackOverflow, even when narrowed down to the people who are interested in Oracle/IIS.

Comment: It doesn't look like a particularly bad question. Maybe the Oracle/IIS Gurus are on holiday.

Comment: It's Easter holidays - certainly the sites I mod have had low visit stats for the last 3 days

Comment: Ah okay, still SO has so many users, I would have thought more than six would have come across it. Oh well. Thanks guys!

Comment: SO has more users, but *even more* questions

Comment: So to summarize you guys, 6 views a day seems like a reasonable distribution for a normal-nothing-wrong-here question? If that's the general consensus I'd be happy with that. The only thing is, I guess in the past I'm used to having many more views for my questions. Perhaps my previous questions have been ... more interesting ;)

Comment: The question is probably very specific. And it is quite short. This is not a bad thing per se but maybe a few ideas what you already tried to solve the idea, would give people some more angle to answer it.

Comment: THat's good advice @Trilarion and I will do that in the future, but people still woulnd't have viewed it even if the content was better.

Comment: @Ev. That's true. I guess every question here on SO relies on either someone else having similar problems or someone else stumbling by chance over it or someone else systematically searching and helping or subscribing to the relevant tags. I guess the experts in your field who could answer the question were not interested enough. To make the incentive higher, you could put a bounty on your question.

Comment: @Trilarion thanks for the advice :) I may give that a spin. As long as there's not something majorly wrong with my account, then I'm happy

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's an hypothesis, born of observation: although the combination of `oracle` and `iis` is absolutely warranted by the contents of your question, this combination makes people decide to skip your question.

If I check in the list of questions that have both tags, the first thing I notice is that there are a total of 43 questions on SO that have both tags. That's not much. Then if I check the number of view of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765509/c-net-connection-to-oracle-database-error) with these tags that came before yours chronologically, it was asked on March 31st and has only 36 views. The [one before that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675453/unhandled-execution-error-when-connecting-to-oracle-from-iis-hosted-web-applic) was asked March 26th and has 39 views.

So it seems to me the main issue is that there are not very many people who feel confident looking at the two technologies together. It's not your question, it's the combination of technologies. (I also don't think that Easter is a major factor.)

Note here I'm not suggesting that you should tag your question differently. It would just annoy people if they click on the question and find that the tags do not reflect the contents.

This, by the way, is a phenomenon I've seen happen with tags I'm active in. I regularly see questions that are tagged with `requirejs` and `javascript`, and that after 4 hours have not received even one answer. When I read the question, I see the problem is a JavaScript one, which normally would have been answered within minutes. Most likely `requirejs` caused people to skip the question because they thought it was a RequireJS problem and they don't know how to use it.

(Dear readers: I've removed the [tag:] formatting from my post because it badly messes up the line height. Please don't add it back in.)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, and confirms my suspicion.

Comment: This answer seems to make a lot of sense and has evidence to back it up. Thanks @Louis

Answer (score 6):

You have several high-volume tags there, so that can't be the problem.

The title is a bit long and elaborate. Also having a title that is identical with the body is not nice*.

I would try shortening the title a bit - say to

> Sharing an Oracle connection pool in IIS

Also, generally, make sure you're using the right terms. Is "connection pooling" really a thing in this context? (A Google search suggests that it is; just making an example.) Are you sure what you are looking for can really be done? etc.

It is so specific an issue, though, that it's well possible that there simply is only a very limited audience for the question.

<sub>* (That can't have an effect on the views though, as you'd see that only when you've opened the question.)</sub>

Comment: "Also having a title that is identical with the body is not nice" - actually Robert changed it to that (which makes sense, since the previous title didn't really summarize the question, which may have led to less views).

Comment: Ahhh the title thing! Someone just changed that for me (correct, @Dukeling :-) Thanks for the input @Pekka!