# Why does this user have no meta profile

Tags: support, meta, users

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93733/ev) user has no meta profile.
Why, I wonder?
He posted [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251074/why-does-my-so-question-have-so-few-views) questioned and it is not attached to his account.

Comment: That question was **migrated** from another site, where he does have an account. If he ever visits here, the account will be created and the question attached to it.

Comment: Found it interesting that a users question can be moved to a forum where he has no account. For that, you get a question at 0 instead of -1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because they never created one.

A Meta profile is only created if the user ever visits Meta while logged in, not before.

The post you link to was migrated from [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/229494/revisions) to here; the user *does* have [an account there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/258776/ev).